Trouble migrating to numpy 2: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
I maintain openTSNE and would like to support numpy2. The package depends on numpy and uses Cython, so the build process is a bit more involved.
When building the package on Azure's CI servers, I previously depended on oldest-supported-numpy for maximum numpy backwards compatibility, but with numpy2, my understanding is that I don't need to do this anymore. Therefore, my pyproject.toml changed to
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "cython", "numpy"]  # was `oldest-supported-numpy` before
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

As far as I can tell, this works fine.
However, I am now getting a new error on my CI servers. You can find the full logs here.
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/runner/work/1/s/tests/test_utils.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_utils.py:4: in <module>
    from openTSNE.utils import clip_point_to_disc
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openTSNE/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from .tsne import TSNE, TSNEEmbedding, PartialTSNEEmbedding, OptimizationInterrupt
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openTSNE/tsne.py:11: in <module>
    from openTSNE import _tsne
openTSNE/_tsne.pyx:1: in init openTSNE._tsne
    ???
E   ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import (auto-generated because you didn't call 'numpy.import_array()' after cimporting numpy; use '<void>numpy._import_array' to disable if you are certain you don't need it).

The numpy docs state that I should now explicitly call np.import_array() in my cython files (https://numpy.org/devdocs/numpy_2_0_migration_guide.html#c-api-changes) and the cython docs provide a simple example. However, I am still running into this error. I have tried to remedy this by adding the import at the beginning of all my .pyx and .pxd files, as indicated by the cython example, e.g.,
cimport numpy as cnp
cnp.import_array()  # <--- HERE
import numpy as np
...
# function definitions

This didn't resolve the issue, so I also added these calls into every cpdef function in the file, e.g.,
cpdef double[:, ::1] compute_gaussian_perplexity(
    double[:, :] distances,
    double[:] desired_perplexities,
    double perplexity_tol=1e-8,
    Py_ssize_t max_iter=200,
    Py_ssize_t num_threads=1,
):
    cnp.import_array()  # <--- HERE
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t n_samples = distances.shape[0]
        Py_ssize_t n_scales = desired_perplexities.shape[0]
    ...

but nothing seems to resolve the issue.
I would note that this only happens in my Release pipeline and not in my Test pipeline. In my Test pipeline, I essentially run only two commands:
pip install .
pytest -v

My Release pipeline, however is more involved, and involves first building the wheels, installing the produced wheel, and then running the test suite on this wheel. The error only occurs in this second Release pipeline. The sequence of commands is roughly
python -m cibuildwheel --output-dir dist/
python -m pip install --force-reinstall --find-links dist openTSNE
pytest  # <--- FAILS

I am somewhat at a loss of what else to try at this point, so any help would be appreciated.

Looking at https://github.com/pavlin-policar/openTSNE/compare/master...numpy-2, I think you've gone over the top with the cnp.import_array in you code. You should just need to once at the top of your .pyx files, e.g., import numpy as np, cimport numpy as np, np.import_array().

Probably also worth updating the python_requires=">=3.8" in your setup.py to be python_requires=">=3.9".

I figured the same, but I reasoned that if I could get it working with using it everywhere, I could gradually remove them until it stopped working. Unfortunately, even with this excessive code, it doesn't seem to be working. Thanks for reminding me about the python version! I missed that.

Looks like you've got the CI working now. Was the main issue that it just wasn't running from your numpy-2 branches?

So, the issue was that I hadn't bumped the version up from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2. So, in my release pipeline, I was building wheels for v1.0.1, but when I installed the packages, it would pull them down from PyPI. The packages from PyPI are compiled against numpy 1.x, so they failed when testing it on the numpy 2.x installed in the environment. I've ran across this issue before and it frustrates me every time since it's so easy to miss. For some reason, I can't get it to prefer local packages over PyPI packages even when using --find-links. If you have any experience with this, that would a big help.
